# Asset Inventory Database Design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I work in an IT shop and am trying to create a database to track our hardware inventory. The gist is, a barcoded asset can only be in one location, either a desk, in a rack, or in some kind of storage (on a shelf, pallet, etc).

I originally had something like this.

```
Table Asset(barcode);
Table Rack(rack_id, rackName);
Table Desk(desk_id, deskName);
Table Storage(storage_id, StorageName);
```

And for each "location" table (Rack, Desk, Storage) I had a table to keep track of where an asset was placed:

```
Table Desk_Item (desk_item_id, desk_id, barcode);
Table Rack_Item (rack_item_id, rack_id, barcode);
Table Storage_Item (storage_item_id, storage_id, barcode);
```

But I didn't like the idea of having three separate tables to keep track of the assets. So I figured I should make a Location table

```
Table Location(location_id, barcode);
Table Rack(rack_id, rackName, location_id);
Table Desk(desk_id, deskName, location_id);
Table Storage(storage_id, StorageName, location_id);
Table Asset(barcode);
```

So now the Location table keeps track of where the asset is. But what weirds me out is that if I query the Location table, I have to check Rack, Desk and Storage. Is that the correct way to design this? Appreciate any thoughts or advice.

Comment: Why need a location table at all? An Asset is somewhere, always. Store it in the Asset table

Comment: That makes sense. I was so caught up with physically "putting" an asset in a location that I carried that thinking over to the database. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a `location_type` table.

```
location_type_id    location_type
      1             Rack
      2             Desk
      3             Storage
```

This also have the advantage if you later want add another `location_type` like **ex:** `'truck'` you dont have to modify the db, just add a new `type`

And instead of multiple table for `Rack`, `Desk`, `Storage` a single table `location`

```
location_id      location_type_id  name
    1                  1           'Im a Rack'
    2                  1           'Im another Rack'
    3                  2           'Im just a desk'
```

Finally your `Assets` table

```
barcode          location_id
 xxxxxx              1            -- is in first rack
 yyyyyy              2            -- is in the second rack
```

Comment: I'm liking this. My tables are a little more complex than what I have shown, but I'll see how I can work these ideas in. Thank you.